# Problema al acceder a la base de datos de postgres

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, debian

He reinstalado el postgres y cuando intento acceder a el usando psql me aparece esto

```
psql: error: falló la conexión al servidor en el socket «/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432»: No existe el fichero o el directorio
        ¿Está el servidor en ejecución localmente y aceptando conexiones en ese socket?
```

Al comprobar el estado del servidor para ver si funcionaba me aparecia asi

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2023-11-05 18:35:42 CET; 3min 11s ago
    Process: 724 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 724 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms

nov 05 18:35:42 debian systemd[1]: Starting postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS...
nov 05 18:35:42 debian systemd[1]: Finished postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Lo he reiniciado y todo pero nada no se que puedo hacer. Estoy trabajando en debian

Comment: estará corriendo postgresql por el puerto por defecto(5432), puedes comprobar cual esta usando, a lo mejor es otro

Comment: Puedes ejecutar el siguiente comando y pegar aquí que retorna?
pg_lsclusters